# How to see the trace logs of IIS server?

Tags: iis

I get the error below when trying to run my asp.net mvc solution:

[image]

This error is located in my WCF service.

**My question is: how can I see the trace logs of the IIS server?**

Below is the configuration of my Visual Studio project:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what OS and IIS version are you using?

Comment: Windows Seven Family Edition Premium + IIS 6.1

Comment: default location for logs is usually `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles` but depends on your [IIS version](https://www.sumologic.com/blog/iis-log-files-location/#:~:text=IIS%20Logs%20Location%3A%20On%20a,%5Clogs%5CLogFiles%20by%20default.) Once you found the log use [SvcTraceViewer.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/service-trace-viewer-tool-svctraceviewer-exe) to view the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up Logging in IIS from IIS not Visual Studio.

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d29207e8-5274-4f4b-9a00-9433b73252d6.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I don't see how this answered the question highlighted in bold?